# Which variant of ssh "jump host" should I use?

Tags: ssh

There are at least 3 variants of `ssh` config known to me which enable `jump_host` usage to connect to the `target_host`:

```
Host jump_host
  HostName 1.2.3.4

# Variant - 1
Host target_host
  HostName 172.16.0.1
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -x jump_host 'netcat %h 22'

# Variant - 2
Host target_host
  HostName 172.16.0.1
  ProxyCommand ssh -q -x jump_host -W '%h:22'

# Variant - 3
Host target_host
  HostName 172.16.0.1
  ProxyJump jump_host
```

Is any of these methods somehow better than the others? What's the difference (if there's any) between config 2 and 3? Obviously config 1 requires to have `netcat` at hand, so it's least appealing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variant 1 will authenticate twice. Once with the proxycommand to establish the connection and again with the original ssh command. You could also make Varient 1 simply `netcat %h %p` instead and use the Host parameters to accomplish the same thing you want out of your ssh command.

```
Host target_host
  HostName 172.16.0.1
  LogLevel QUIET
  ForwardX11 no
  ProxyCommand netcat %h %p
```

However even with this it would require a pty to support netcat and an extra process as part of the conneciton.

Variant 2 does the same thing as netcat but internally and does not allocate a pty although this can be overridden to be exactly like variant 1 if that were desired. It also prevents any setup on the jumphost like agent forwarding.

Variant 1 and 2 are using ProxyCommand which is there as a generic way to automate the setup of the connection. Primarily these variants exist because ProxyJump only existed after it. But ProxyCommand can be used to do more advanced things with the connection setup. The documentation cites examples of using it to setup HTTP CONNECT proxies to forward your connection.

Variant 3 uses ProxyJump which is essentially a built in TCP proxy and is most similar to Variant 2 but allows for simpler and stricter manor of chaining. Without it doing the same thing would look like this:

```
Host jumphost2
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost1
Host server
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumphost2
```

But with ProxyJump would look like this:

```
Host server
  ProxyJump jumphost2,jumphost1
```